# stop rufus-scheduler job from ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rufus-scheduler

how can i stop rufus-scheduler from my script :

```
@scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
job = @scheduler.schedule_every '3m' do |job|
  # processing
end
job.call
```

I just want to test in first step if the job is running if true stop the job.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a standalone script that shows how to do it:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

job = scheduler.schedule_every '1s' do
  # processing...
  sleep 3600
end

# later on...

sleep 2

p job.running?   # true

job.kill if job.running?

p job.running?   # false
```

Documentation: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/#job-methods

If you can't keep the job instance around but can keep a string, you could do:

```
job_id = scheduler.every '3m' do
  # processing...
end

# later on...

job = scheduler.job(job_id)
```

Documentation: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/#schedulerjobjob_id

Comment: Understandable! But when I use it, it says `running` or `kill` is undefined? Anything I ll have to predefine to have these commands implemented? I have the jobs scheduled in rufus and they run fine, but, I am looking for something that would kill the job on the time mentioned.

Comment: Please ask a new, detailed, question.

Comment: My question is nothing different from the question you have answered. However, the error undefined. is something that I am getting on running the `kill` command, which again comes as a question to the answer you provided. Hence, If you don't helping out here. Else, stackoverflow and its vigilantes, would ask me to go through this question or keep my new question on hold.

Comment: Please ask a new, detailed, question.